# Writing to two files using functions and arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, file, function

I tried everything and what I have is something I know is incorrect but at least the output is formatted how I need it for one of the two files. I need to send information out into two separate .txt files that both carry different information. How do I do that using the current array functions I already have. I have spent hours trying to figure this out and now its up to you all! Thank you.

Main-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include "Payroll.h"
using namespace std;


const int NUM_EMPLOYEE = 75;

int main()
{
    int dependents;
    double payrate;
    string name;
    double hours;
    ifstream fin;
    int count = 0;
    Payroll employeeArray[NUM_EMPLOYEE];

    fin.open("employeeData.txt");

    if (!fin)
    {
        cout << "Error opening data file\n";
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        while(fin >> payrate >> dependents)
        {
            getline(fin, name);
            employeeArray[count].setWage(payrate);
            employeeArray[count].setDependents(dependents);
            employeeArray[count].setName(name);
            cout << "How many hours has" << name << " worked? ";
                cin >> hours;
                employeeArray[count].setHours(hours);
            count++;
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        employeeArray[i].printPayDetails(cout << endl);
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Print Function-

```
void Payroll::printPayDetails(ostream& out)
{
    double normPay = getNormPay();
    double overTime = getOverPay();
    double grossPay = getGrossPay();
    double taxAmount = getTaxRate();
    double netPay = computePay();
    const int SIZE = 9;
    out << fixed << setprecision(2) << right << setw(5) << hours  << setw(SIZE)  << normPay << setw(SIZE) << overTime ;
    out << setw(SIZE) << grossPay << setw(SIZE) << taxAmount <<setw(SIZE) << netPay;
}
```

Comment: What result are you trying to achieve? You haven't really asked a specific question.

Also, is this homework?

Comment: If you are asking how to write output to different files, try googling "c++ file stream"

Comment: You're currently printing to standard output. You won't get that to be sent to 2 different files. You managed to get `ifstream` to work, so `ofstream` shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: I want to call the print function in main to write to my two files. When I do it the loops dont work and they only send the last line of information from the .txt input file. Can I open and close the two .txt output files in the function?

Comment: When you try something new, try it in isolation, don't graft it into a large preexisting program. Try to write the shortest, simplest program that will write two different words to two different files. If it works, *then* you can integrate it into other stuff; if it doesn't, it'll be much easier to tinker with.

Comment: **What two files?** All I see is an input file and a dump to stdout.

Answer (score 2):

Your question wording is a bit shaky but I think I get what you're saying. If you want to output to two different file you're going to need two string streams. Below is an example:

```
#include <fstream>

void main()
{
     //Open file 1
     ofstream file1;
     file1.open("file1.txt");
     file1 << "Writing stuff to file 1!";

     //Open file 2
     ofstream file2;
     file2.open("file2.txt");
     file2 << "Writing stuff to file 2!";

     //That the files are open you can pass them as arguments to the rest of your functions.
     //Remember to use &


     //At the end of your program remember to close the files
     file1.close();
     file2.close();
}
```